# Is this grammatical? "You are who I love."

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses, questions

I've just got wondering if this sentence is grammatically correct:

> You are who I love.

---

This is what I am thinking:

Let's focus on the *who* clause, then you can find that the missing element from this clause is actually an object after the verb *love*. Therefore, *who* should be changed to *whom*, which is an object relative pronoun.

- You are whom I love.

Now, the whom clause has no problem, but you can see that whom clause works as an object. However, there is the place at which a subject complement should be. So, I should either change the whom clause back to a who clause or make *you* into an object.

1. You is whom I love.
2. It's you whom I love.
3. Whom I love is you.

After all that, I came this far with these three sentences and I think the most appropriate sentence is the second one, but I'm not sure if my assumption is right; the way I fixed the sentence, is it right?

Comment: 1 and 3 are ungrammatical. 2 is grammatical, but it's not a "fix" either, merely a rewording. Any sentence at all can be reworded. Language is flexible like that. There's many ways to skin a cat. There are many ways to skin a cat. There's more than one way to skin a cat.

Comment: The most appropriate sentences are 4. _I love you._ or 5. _You're the one I love._ These avoid the need for the largely obsolescent 'whom' (though (2) is just about bearable; however, more idiomatic would be _It's you that I love._). _It's you I love._ is another workaround.

Comment: Also, I think "you are whom I love" is actually more likely than "you are who I love", though for reasons of articulation ([Sandhi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandhi)) rather than grammar.

Comment: I don't understand your sentence ***However, there is the place at which a subject complement should be.*** Can you explain what you mean, please :)

Comment: @Araucaria Well, first, be aware that sentence is also a part of my assumption. What I meant there is, since the verb is *are*, after which a subject complement should come. For example, "He is a man;" *He* is the subject and *a man* is a subject complement.

Comment: @ㄱㄴㄷ Ah, I see. But a subject complement isn't a subject. It just means a predicative complement which describes the subject. We can contrast this with a predicative complement which describes an object:  "We elected him treasurer" where *treasurer* is a complement describing the object. The fact that it's a subject complement doesn't mean it should be a "subject" relative pronoun. For example in the sentence "It was him" the word "him" is a so-called object pronoun ... See what I mean?

Comment: @Araucaria Oh, what you're saying is also one of the reasons I asked this question. "It's him" and  "it's me;" these are common sentences and idiomatic, but I once heard that "it's I" and "it's he" are technically correct, which made me think that subject complements should be subjects. In terms of grammar, can object pronouns be subject complements?

Comment: @ㄱㄴㄷ Yes, they nearly always are! (when they're pronouns)

Comment: @Araucaria Thanks. I've just found it here, [http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/subject-complements](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/subject-complements).

Comment: Perhaps consider: *"Who do I love?" --> "Who I love is you." --> "You are who I love."*

Comment: Unless you're in love with a grammarian (whom you're trying to impress), you should probably just go with "I love you."

Comment: Related ELL question: [Is “I was who sent you the letter” grammatically correct?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/88508)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original is probably eliding a word.

I think this works:

You are she whom I love.

'are' is a linking verb here; 'whom' is introducing an appositive phrase and is the object of 'love'.  What's missing in the original is the predicate pronoun ('she', 'he', etc.).

Comment: Sounds stilted to me. The form _whom_ is stilted, unless it immediately follows a preposition.

Comment: Tim Osborne is right. What we say is of course "You are the one that I love."